# Muted autoplay videos stop playing in Safari 11.0

Tags: html, video, safari, autoplay

I have these videos on my site with attributes listed below:

```
<video width="100%" poster="poster_url.png" autoplay loop muted playsinline>
<source src="video_url.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Everything worked just fine until I’ve installed Safari 11. This version shows poster images and does not autoplay videos even though they don't have an audio track. Take a look at it on my [site](http://www.grabelnikov.com/#plentiful).

I saw autoplay videos working [on other sites](http://www.elirousso.com/) (even without muted property) on my own laptop in Safari.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: your comment 0% relates to the OPs post @anonymous

Comment: My blog post summing up findings might help -> 
https://medium.com/@BoltAssaults/autoplay-muted-html5-video-safari-ios-10-in-react-673ae50ba1f5

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yup, it appears Safari is also blocking muted video's (that don't even have sound)...

I have found a workaround, but it isn't pretty and I'm not proud of it:

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var is_safari = (ua.indexOf("safari/") > -1 && ua.indexOf("chrome") < 0);
if(is_safari) {
    var video = document.getElementById('#video-element-id');
    setTimeout(function() {
       video.play();
    }, 50);
}
```

I have tried doing this without the timeout, but Safari is rejecting this by throwing a Promise rejection.
I don't know why...

Comment: not working on my side or not working for safari > 12

Comment: Seems like you are just delaying play, which indicates you are not calling the play function after the video metadata load event

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this issue as well for a short mp4 that played in the background of a website. I was able to get a solution working for iOS Safari 11 without the need for JS by qualifying the video tag with `controls="true"` and `playsinline`.

Example:

```
<video autoplay loop playsinline muted controls="true" src="~/background.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

**Note:** Safari doesn't support .webm so don't be like me and struggle with that for longer than you'd like to admit.

Comment: also does not work. in my case i have videos that autoplay perfectly with `playsinline` but i'm trying to toggle mute on a user gesture of clicking a certain button (can't show controls). adding in the controls attribute doesn't allow toggling of the volume as i'm doing. my project works in desktop chrome/desktop ff - just not desktop safari/mobile safari.

Comment: was at my wits end because the issue didn't make sense. turns out a nuxt module for vuejs was butchering ranged requests. apologies if i offended you.

Answer (score 4):

The most reliable way I've found is to ensure:

- at least one user interaction on the page (chrome mobile)
- muted attribute on  tag (all)
- playsinline attribute on  tag (safari)

Which looks like this:

```
<style>
  video {
    display: none;
  }
  video.active {
    display: block;
  }
</style>
<button id="button">Show video</button>
<video id="video" muted playsinline></video>
<script>
    var button = document.getElementById('button');
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        video.className = 'active';
        video.src = 'https://archive.org/download/BigBuckBunny_124/Content/big_buck_bunny_720p_surround.mp4';
        video.play();
    });
</script>
```

One trick is to reuse the same video player for each video. Then it only needs to be activated the first time. Every consecutive play can occur automatically.

Comment: "playsinline"..? wow... :D never heard of it before, THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

Put the `src` attribute inside the <video> instead of using <source>

```
<video src="video_url.mp4" width="100%" poster="poster_url.png" autoplay loop muted playsinline></video>
```

With <source> it only works if the element is in view when the page loads (tested on safari 11.0)

A link of [Auto-Play Policy Changes for macOS](https://webkit.org/blog/7734/auto-play-policy-changes-for-macos/).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem and solved it with the canplaythrough event (or the canplay event). This might solve the need for setTimeout in Abayob's solution:

```
const video = document.getElementById('#video-element-id');
video.oncanplaythrough = function() {
    video.play();
}
```