# Playing video automatically on Safari won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

When I open my website in Safari (desktop) my video usually starts automatically. I know in the past it already won't play automatic on iPad or iPhone but not on desktop.

It's like Safari set new rules. Is there a way to play the videos automatically? Because there is a website that I've found that still automatically play videos on their website on Safari.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Muted autoplay videos stop playing in Safari 11.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46745684/muted-autoplay-videos-stop-playing-in-safari-11-0)

Comment: var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
       var is_safari = (ua.indexOf("safari/") > -1 && ua.indexOf("chrome") < 0);
    if(is_safari) {
    var video = document.getElementById('#video-element-id');
    setTimeout(function() {
       video.play();
    }, 50);
}

Comment: when i use this code it just give one error still... TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'video.play')

Comment: `document.getElementById('#video-element-id')` should not have a `#`. Change to `document.getElementById('video-element-id')`. This is assuming that your `video` has the `id` "video-element-id"

Comment: i still get the old error : [Error] Unhandled Promise Rejection: NotAllowedError (DOM Exception 35): The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission. (x107)

Comment: also this one: Unhandled Promise Rejection: [object DOMError]

Answer (score 5):

This can be circumvented using the following properties:

`<video muted playsinline autoplay></video>`

But autoplaying with the sound turned on is indeed not possible anymore. More information can be found [on webkit.org](https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/).

Answer (score 5):

I have Mojave and found a solution that worked for a site I use often.

One can go to the top bar menu:

Safari Preferences -> The 'Websites' (tab heading) -> Auto-Play (left side)

As the default websites `Auto-Play` option is `Stop Media with Sound`, this strategy introduced the permission issue.

[image: Safari Preferences]

Allow media from that site. One can turn it on at the bottom of that box for all sites.

There is a simpler way in the same menu next to Safari Prefrences, called 'Settings for This Website' -- it allows you to make that same setting, and a few others rather than having to poke around the rest of the Settings box.

Clearly that means a user has to allow it.

The site where I found a working example: https://support.shadowhealth.com/hc/en-us/articles/360009548313-Audio-issues-in-Safari

I did post the way to do it above so the site is not needed if they ever take it down, but they did do nice screen shots. I put it here for handy reference.

To deal with browsers who 'wander' to your location, you would need to provide a button to launch videos or audio clips.

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to the fact that apple is blocking this add-on
https://techcrunch.com/2017/06/05/auto-play-block/

Comment: var vid = document.getElementById('video-element-id');
    setTimeout(function(){
        
        vid.play();
       vid.muted = false;

Comment: this works only if i don't use the vid.muted = false;

Comment: `var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var is_safari = (ua.indexOf("safari/") > -1 && ua.indexOf("chrome") < 0);
if(is_safari) {
    var video = document.getElementById('#video-element-id');
    setTimeout(function() {
       video.play();
    }, 50);
}`

Comment: found this workaround on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46745684/muted-autoplay-videos-stop-playing-in-safari-11-0

Comment: yeah but if i add vidoe.mute = false; the video won't start even. i gues i'll have to make a sound on button

Comment: Yes unfortunately that looks like the only way to go.

Comment: I dont know if it will work it could be a long shot try setting a timer on the that performs the button click for you   `document.getElementById('<%= savebtn.ClientID %>').click();
     `

Comment: okay i setted a button to play the sound but when i click a sound on image must appear but that won't happen. it gives this error 5soundOnn.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Please provide me with some code so I can try and see where this error is