# Muted Autoplay Not Working on iphone Safari 11.3

Tags: javascript, ios, html5-video, mobile-safari

I set all the required attributes  in video tag but nothing works for me.
If I play video with no sound, it works on all the browsers except iphone safari.
Low Power Mode is also disabled on the iphone and iphone was also connected to wifi. Don't know if it is due to any other phone settings which is preventing autoplay or some guideline that I am missing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Muted autoplay videos stop playing in Safari 11.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46745684/muted-autoplay-videos-stop-playing-in-safari-11-0)

Comment: Does your video have the `playsinline` attribute?

Comment: What version of iOS?

Comment: I have summed up my findings related to different safari version shenanigans for autoplaying muted videos in a blog. Hope this helps

https://medium.com/@BoltAssaults/autoplay-muted-html5-video-safari-ios-10-in-react-673ae50ba1f5