# HTML5 Video with custom button not playable on safari 12

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, safari, html5-video

Safari has blocked autoplay from videos which are completely understandable. But I have to find a **workaround** that a video is playing "automatically". 
I use **VueJS** btw.

The video:

```
<video preload="auto" id="videowizy" class="video mockup-size">
    <source src="../assets/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

This video is **only played when pressed on a custom play button**.

```
<a id="play" @click="startVideo">Play Video ▶</a>
```

And I start it with the **.play();** function.

```
this.videoStarted = true;
window.setTimeout(() => {
    this.videoVisible = true;
    var video = document.getElementById('videowizy');
    video.addEventListener('ended',this.stopVideo,false);
    video.play();
},2000)
```

Now to the question. Safari 12 is throwing me the following error

> Unhandled Promise Rejection: NotAllowedError: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.

I would be fixed when I use controls=true but when I use controls=true I cannot press play because the **video is positioned absolutely behind a frame** (to simulate a mockup of a phone).
Is there a way to say "hey this is the play button, please let me play safari"?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46745684/muted-autoplay-videos-stop-playing-in-safari-11-0

Comment: nope no duplicate. Same problem but the solution is not working on safari > 12

Comment: Upgrading to iOS 12.2 broke HTML5 video in our app's WebView, and we use native HTML5 controls. Attempting to `play()` throws the same error you've quoted.

Comment: Any fixes for this yet?